# How to Enable Touch Events For a MapView underneath a UIView (iOS8/Swift)

Tags: ios, uiview, swift

This is a question that has been asked before however the solution does to appear to work as it used to, or there is another problem occurring.

I have a MapView, and on top of it I have placed an opaque UIView that acts as an indicator for the user. This has been done in the interface builder, so no manual placement of controls or anything like that. I want the UIView to NOT block user interactions with the MapView such as double-tap to zoom, pan, etc. I have tried the existing solution which is to uncheck the box "User Interaction Enabled" in the interface builder for the UIView, however that has not worked.

How can I solve this?

I will post code if it turns out that iOS8/XCode 6 does not effect this solution.

Code: https://github.com/ChrisChares/swift-alarm *Github Repo, note that this is not my code, but it reflects the problem shown here. Goto the MapViewController interface.*

Comment: Are you sure it's called "Enable Gesture Recognizer"?

Comment: I mean't "User Interaction Enabled", thanks for noticing.

Comment: I see no reason that Xcode 6 or iOS 8 would change anything here; perhaps you can post a minimal example that produces this behavior?

Comment: Could be also that iOS 8 is still in the beta. Once iOS 7 betas came out - so much was broken of the default features.

Comment: I added a github repo above that works as an example, just select the UIView square in the MapViewController and uncheck the box "User Interaction Enabled". It still blocks the gestures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I figured it out, this could be a potential glitch in Xcode 6, or Apple has intentionally changed certain logic in the options panels.

Toggling the User Interaction Enabled box does not fix the problem as noted earlier.

However, doing this using code does, simply use:

targetView.userInteractionEnabled = false
and you will notice the MapView properly registers the touches from the UIView.

Answer (score 0):

How about overriding this UIView's hittest method, and returning nil? I can't test with ios8 sim at the moment, so that's just a guess.

Comment: Are you referring to this? `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Comment: Yes, also possibly overriding this might help: - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event.